# Reading From File With Comma Delimeter Error

Tags: java, arraylist, io, readfile

Here's the .txt file i'm trying to read from

```
20,Dan,09/05/1990,3,Here
5,Danezo,04/09/1990,99,There
```

And here's how I'm doing it.. Whenever the .txt file has only one line, it seems to be reading from file fine. Whenever more than one line is being read, I get this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Danezo"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
at AttackMonitor.readFromFile(AttackMonitor.java:137)
at AttackMonitor.monitor(AttackMonitor.java:57)
at MonsterAttackDriver.main(MonsterAttackDriver.java:14)
Java Result: 1
```

Here's the readfromfile code.

```
 private void readFromFile() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
    {
        monsterAttacks.clear();
        Scanner read = new Scanner(new File("Attacks.txt"));
        read.useDelimiter(",");
        String fullDateIn = "";
        int attackIdIn = 0;
        int attackVictimsIn = 0;
        String monsterNameIn= "";
        String attackLocationIn= "";
        while (read.hasNext())
        {
           attackIdIn = Integer.parseInt(read.next());
           monsterNameIn = read.next();
           fullDateIn = read.next();
           attackVictimsIn = Integer.parseInt(read.next());
           attackLocationIn = read.next();
           monsterAttacks.add(new MonsterAttack(fullDateIn, attackIdIn, attackVictimsIn, monsterNameIn, attackLocationIn));

        }
        read.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

What is happening is that at the end of each line there is a newline character, which is currently *not* a delimiter.  So your code is attempting to read it as the *first* integer of the next line, which it is not.  This is causing the parse exception.

To remedy this, you can try adding newline to the list of delimiters for which to scan:

```
Scanner read = new Scanner(new File("Attacks.txt"));
read.useDelimiter("[,\r\n]+");  // use just \n on Linux
```

An alternative to this would be to just read in each entire line from the file and split on comma:

```
String[] parts = read.nextLine().split(",");

attackIdIn = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
monsterNameIn = parts[1];
fullDateIn = parts[2];
attackVictimsIn = Integer.parseInt(parts[3]);
attackLocationIn = parts[4];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the  Biegeleisen suggestion. Or else you can do as follows.
In your while loop you are using `hasNext` as condition. Instead of that you can use  `while (read.hasNextLine())` and get the nextLine inside the loop and then split it by your delimiter and do the processing. That would be a more appropriate approach.

e.g

```
while (read.hasNextLine()) {
    String[] values = scanner.nextLine().split(".");
    // do your rest of the logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the while loop content in a try catch, and catch for NumberFormatException. So whenever it falls to catch code, you can understand you tried to convert a string to int.
Could help more if your business is explained.

Answer (score -1):

`attackLocationIn = read.next();` This value takes as "Here\n 5" because there is no comma between Here and 5 and it has new line character.
so 2nd iteration `attackIdIn = Integer.parseInt(read.next());` here `read.next()` value is "Danezo" it is String and you are trying parse to Integer. That's why you are getting this exception.

What I suggest is use `BufferReader` to read line by line and split each line with comma. It will be fast also.

Or another solution Add comma at end of each line and use `read.next().trim()` in your code. That's it it will work with minimal changes to your current code.